# Can I typeset a proof tree in exercise 2.4.3(c) from mathematical logic by ian chiswell and wilfrid hodges(2007) with tex?

Tags: trees

The picture below is exercise 2.4.3(c).

[image]

Comment: You should add what you have looked up and tried so far (pstricks, tikz, ...)

Comment: by the looks of the picture, the book actually is typeset with TeX. People here are very helpful, but even more so when they get the impression that you've already put some effort in solving the problem yourselv, e.g. by showing your (unsuccessful) attempts.

Comment: I haven't learned Tex or LaTex yet. But, I want to know if it's "possible" to typeset the above picture with Tex/LaTex.

Comment: Of course it's possible. The only question is: which way is the most appropriate?

Comment: It is possible but a bit advanced. If you don't know any LaTeX yet, it is definitely not worth learning it, just for the sake of one tree. But if you are planning to work extensively in this or similar fields, it's probably a really good idea to get going with a good [LaTeX-introduction](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner) and get back to trees after a while.

Comment: Can it be done with ConTeXt, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several packages to draw proof trees in LaTeX, e.g., `bussproofs`, `ebproof`,`prftrees`.  Here is a solution using `bussproofs` to draw the proof tree and `cancel` to slash one of the assumption.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{\qquad\textcircled{\scriptsize1}}
  \noLine
  \UnaryInfC{$\cancel\psi$}
\AxiomC{$\phi\wedge\psi$}
  \RightLabel{($\wedge$E)}
  \UnaryInfC{$\phi$}
    \RightLabel{($\wedge$I).}
    \insertBetweenHyps{\hskip2cm}
    \BinaryInfC{$(\psi\wedge\phi)$}
      \LeftLabel{\textcircled{\scriptsize 1}}
      \RightLabel{($\rightarrow$I)}
      \UnaryInfC{$(\psi\rightarrow(\psi\wedge\phi))$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

With `ebproof` the same proof tree can be achieved with the following code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}[template=$\inserttext$]
\Hypo{\quad\textcircled{\scriptsize 1}}
\Infer[no rule]1{\cancel\psi}
\Hypo{(\phi\wedge\psi)}
\Infer1[($\wedge$E)]{\phi}
\Infer[separation=2cm]2[($\wedge$I)]{(\psi\wedge\phi)}  
\Infer[left label=\textcircled{\scriptsize 1}, 
       right label=($\rightarrow$I)]1{(\psi\rightarrow(\psi\wedge\phi))}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `bussproofs` and `cancel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{cancel}

\newcommand{\lto}{\mathbin{\to}}

\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
\renewcommand{\defaultHypSeparation}{\hspace{4em}}
\AxiomC{${\cancel{\psi}}^{\,\raisebox{\depth}{\textcircled{\footnotesize 1}}}$}
\AxiomC{$(\phi\land\psi)$}
\RightLabel{($\land\mathrm{E}$)}
\UnaryInfC{$\phi$}
\RightLabel{($\land\mathrm{I}$)}
\BinaryInfC{$(\psi\land\phi)$}
\LeftLabel{\textcircled{\footnotesize 1}}
\RightLabel{($\lto\mathrm{I}$)}
\UnaryInfC{$(\psi\lto(\psi\land\phi))$}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you type the tex code by hand? or did you use a GUI frontend?

Comment: @crocket Just some lookup in the manual of `bussproofs`. No, there's no front-end for this, as far as I know. But, as you see, the syntax is not bad.